# Prevent 301 when a trailing slash added

Tags: permalinks

I am using Wordpress <del>8.3</del> 4.7 with Gantry theme. I have url with the following format for my categories.

`www.website.com/my-category`

Whenever I have an extra trailing slash my website does a 301. I do not want 301 to happen what do I do to stop that from happening?

Comment: wordpress 8.3? so you are from the future! you can probably tell as all how gutenberg ended up ;)

Comment: So you want `www.website.com/my-category` to 301 to `www.website.com/my-category/`? Having neither of them redirect would mean that to search engines you'd have two URLs with the same content? Trailing slash and non-trailing slash are [treated as separate](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html) URLs and one should redirect to the other. To do this you should just need to add the `/` to your permalink structure.